to_ne_bytes(); rust function python equivalent
I am trying to make a python based .bruh (https://github.com/face-hh/bruh) converter. I was trying to figure out what the raw bytes were, so I checked the code. I found the function and tried searching it up, and I found it in the rust docs.
Is there a way to recreate it and a way to do the opposite in Python?

In order to reverse Rust's u8.to_ne_bytes, take a look at the struct stdlib library.
For example :
import struct

values = struct.unpack("=I", b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde")
print(hex(values[0]))  # 0xdeadbeef

So, read the width and height bytes using the method above, then the pixel values.
